# I can't update a table that has two unique keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `locations`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `locations` (
  `tenant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `waypoint_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `material` int(11),
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tenant_id`,`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY(`waypoint_id`, `material`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

I'm running this query:

```
    UPDATE locations
SET waypoint_id=23,
material=19,
price=22.22,
unit_id=1
WHERE tenant_id=3 AND id = 54;
```

I get the following error:

```
Duplicate entry '23-19' for key 'waypoint_id'
```

I know that I have a record with those IDs already but then how can I edit the values in that row if it doesn't let me change them?

I don't understand why I get this error if I'm not trying to insert a new record with those ids 23-19 but I'm just trying to update that record. How can I solve this?

**NOTE**

I apologize, I pasted the wrong query, I edited the query with the first one that is creating the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems to be wrong. It should be like this:

```
UPDATE locations
SET waypoint_id=23, 
material=19,
price=22.22,
unit_id=1
WHERE tenant_id=3 AND id = 54;
```

**EDIT:**

You need to check that your table doesn't have the waypoint_id as 23 and material as 19 as you have made it as unique. If there is any duplicate entry already present then you cannot add 23 value and 19 value.

You can check it like this:

```
select waypoint_id, material from locations WHERE tenant_id=3 AND id = 54;
```

or rather check like

```
select * from locations where waypoint_id = 23 or material = 19
```

A workaround to your problem is to drop the unique key constraint from your table like this

```
alter table locations drop index waypoint_id ;
alter table locations drop index material ;
```

Then you can do the update

And after that apply the unique key on the combination of two columns like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `locations` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`waypoint_id`, `material`);
```

Comment: Sorry I had to edit my post I pasted the wrong query, anyway I used your query and I got same problem: pastie.org/private/p0v0kdwcuneepzs1h1tpna

Comment: @SaulOrtega:- See the updated answer. It looks like your table is already having the waypoint_id column as 23 and material as 19. So if you will try to update that value  to 23 and 19 respectively then it will result in the error which you are getting now. Since you have made the two columns as unique

Comment: Yes I do have that record already in my table, and I was aware of that but what I want to do is to edit that record not to add a new one with those IDs.

Comment: @SaulOrtega:- So one thing which you can do is that you can drop the unique key constraint from your table like this `alter table locations drop index waypoint_id ;` and then try to update the value.

Comment: well the problem is that I need to have that key constrain in my table, I just don't understand why I can't update that record if I'm not creating a new record.

Comment: @SaulOrtega:- If the column is unique, then you cannot insert duplictaes in that column, thats how unique key constarint works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90582/discussion-between-saul-ortega-and-rahul-tripathi).

Answer (score 1):

```
UNIQUE KEY(`waypoint_id`, `material`)
```

So when you **do** have that constraint, you can not have 2 rows that have same combination for those 2 values. So you cant have two rows with 23 as waypoint_id and 19 as material, simple as that.

That's what unique means. That combination has to be unique whether you update or insert.

<del>Because you cant provide 2 different update queries mixed in one query like that.

    UPDATE locations
    SET waypoint_id=23 WHERE tenant_id=3 AND id = 54

Query ends there.  Now it appears like you do have only 1 update going on but your syntax is not right. It should be like

    UPDATE locations
    SET waypoint_id=23,
    material=19,
    price=22.22,
    unit_id=1
    WHERE tenant_id=3 AND id = 54</del>

Comment: Sorry I had to edit my post I pasted the wrong query, anyway I used your query and I got same problem: http://pastie.org/private/p0v0kdwcuneepzs1h1tpna

Comment: But I'm not trying to insert a new row with 23 as waypoint_id and 19 as material, what I'm doing is updating that row that has 23 as waypoint_id and 19 as material

Comment: Nope thats not what you are doing. You are updating this row `WHERE tenant_id=3 AND id = 54`, not the row you are saying. And this row is different from the one you want to update im 100% sure

Answer (score 0):

Since the user is sure that he is updating the unique row with condition `waypoint_id=23 & material=19`, the query could be as below:

```
UPDATE locations
SET price=22.22, unit_id=1
WHERE waypoint_id=23 AND material=19 /*(AND tenant_id=3 AND id = 54) - condition not required*/;
```